# DEX file referenced type is not defined in file

Tags: android, java, apk

I am analyzing a dex file and to ease with reverse engineering, I converted it a jar so it could be decompiled. In the file `android/support/v17/leanback/media/MediaControllerGlue.class`, the following import appears:

`import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat;`

However, this class is not defined. In fact, there is no `android/support/v4/media` package in the file.

To confirm, this, I listed the referenced type in the `type_ids` section of the dex file, and sure enough, the following type is present: `android/support/v4/media/MediaControllerCompat`. However, when I then iterate over all entries in the `class_defs` section, this class is nowhere to be found.

I am new to Android (this is actually an Amazon Firestick APK) development/reverse engineering so I'm not sure how this is possible. Is there some way of defining classes in a separate library that would exist outside of the APK?

Comment: Did you check whether there are multiple dex files? What tool did you use to do the jar conversion?

Comment: There is only one dex file. I used dex2jar but the problem doesn't lie in the jar conversion since I inspected the contents of the dex file directly.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, this class (and other not defined in the DEX file) are part of the standard Android library. Therefore, I suppose they're linked from a shared object at runtime.